# Install SSM Agent and Role suring Launch on SUSE Linux EC2 Instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, suse, aws-ssm

My customer has no public subnet, has all private subnets without any NAT Gateway and Elastic IP. I have to launch new EC2 instance with SLES 12 and SLES 15 that can be connected through SSM. Will you please guide me how can I install SSM agent and required role during launch of EC2 instance?

I have created a SSM role with AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policy.

I tried the below mentioned commands in bootstarp but it is not working

mkdir /tmp/ssm
cd /tmp/ssm
wget https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/amazon-ssm-ca-central-1/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
sudo rpm --install amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, the ec2 instances may not be able to get connected to the Internet. You can try to bake an image with necessary packages and SSM agent installed then provision the instances with it.